# Parsing into a string from type DateTime

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I am trying to convert a `DateTime` and an `int` property into a string in a foreach loop.  I need to put the information that is stored in the objects properties into the variables and then use that info to write to a text file using StreamWriter.  I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong.  `Parse` is red underlined with this error message -

> Error 2   'string' does not contain a definition for 'Parse'

Here is my code -

```
 public bool Save()
        {
            string appointStart;
            string appointLength;
            string appointDescription;

            foreach (Appointment appointment in appointments)
            {
                appointStart = string.Parse(appointment.Start);
                appointLength = string.Parse(appointment.Length);
                appointDescription = appointment.DisplayableDescription;

            }
            return true;
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: String does *not* have a Parse method. Are you looking for formatting?

Comment: Error message is clear. There is method as `Parse` in `String` class. Can you please show an example input and outputs?

Comment: Parsing is converting *from* a string into a different type. Formatting is converting *from* the other type into a string. So you're not parsing *into* a string - you're formatting a DateTime.

Comment: Just use .ToString().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the ToString() methods of [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/k494fzbf(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Int32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/6t7dwaa5(v=vs.110).aspx) class to get a string representation of the specified types. Some ToString() methods provide overloads to define the formatting of the string value.

```
foreach (Appointment appointment in appointments)
{
  appointStart = appointment.Start.ToString();
  appointLength = appointment.Length.ToString();
  appointDescription = appointment.DisplayableDescription;
}
```

Comment: The OP should also take care to use the proper format strings, to avoid writing unexpected values, eg time values when only dates were expected, US date formats instead of ISO etc

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to Parse the DateTime and int into String?? Because if you just want to have the variables in string format, you can simply use .ToString() or Convert.Tostring()

Comment: Thank you.  I am new to programming and I am learning so I was not aware

Comment: Its okk... Free feel to ask and do me a favour, if my answer was helpful then please mark it as accepted answer and vote it up. Thank You!!